# How to select a key from a discriminated union type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, discriminated-union

I have a disciminated union

```
type MyDUnion = { type: "anon"; name: string } | { type: "google"; idToken: string };
```

I want to access the name key from the discriminative union, from the `MyDUnion` type directly. Something like this

```
type Name = MyDUnion['name']
```

But typescript won't allow that

```
Property 'name' doesn't exist on type '{ type: "anon"; name: string } | { type: "google"; idToken: string }'
```

How can I access it?

To be clear, this is **not** a valid solution:

```
type MyName = string;
type MyDUnion = { type: "anon"; name: MyName } | { type: "google"; idToken: string };
type Name = MyName; // this line would be in a different file
```

This is not valid, because then I would have to export both `MyName` and `MyDUnion` types to be used elsewhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to filter union of objects, usually you need to use [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union):
The easy way:

```js
type Result = Extract<MyDUnion , {type: "anon"}>
```

The more robust:

```js
type MyDUnion = { type: "anon"; name: string } | { type: "google"; idToken: string };

type Filter<Union, Type extends Partial<Union>> = Extract<Union, Type>

type Result = Filter<MyDUnion, { type: 'anon' }>
```

Comment: That is pretty f*ing cool! Is there a better way to express the subset part `Record<keyof Union, Values<Union>>`? I tried putting `Type extends Union` directly, but it wouldn't accept with missing keys. Is there another way to denote a subset?

Comment: @sayandcode thanks, you already have figured it out

Answer (score 3):

## Generic Solution

```
/**
 * @param Union - A discriminated union type to extract properties from.
 * @param Keys - The specific properties to extract from `Union`.
 * @defaultValue all `KeyOf<Union>`
 * @param Otherwise - The type to unionize with value types that don't exist in all members of `Union`.
 * @defaultValue `undefined`
 */
export type PickAll<
    Union,
    Keys extends KeyOf<Union> = KeyOf<Union>,
    Otherwise = undefined
> = {
    [_K in Keys]: Union extends { [K in _K]?: infer Value }
        ? UnionToIntersection<Value>
        : Otherwise
}
```

### helpers

```
type KeyOf<Union, Otherwise = never> = Union extends Union
    ? keyof Union
    : Otherwise
```

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (
    U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never
) extends (k: infer I) => void
    ? I
    : never
```

---

### Target

```
type MyDUnion =
  | { type: 'anon'; name: string }
  | { type: 'google'; idToken: string }
```

### `indexed access` and `keyof`

```
MyDUnion['type']
/* "anon' | "google" */
// OK

MyDUnion[keyof MyDUnion]
/* "anon" | "google" */
// ❓

// @ts-expect-error - not all union members have an idToken
MyDUnion['type' | 'idToken']
/* any */
// ❌
```

### `KeyOf<Union>`

```
type UnionKeys = KeyOf<MyDUnion>
/* "type" | "name" | "idToken" */
// ✅
```

### `PickAll<Union, KeyOf<Union>?, Otherwise?>`

by default, picks *all*

```
type DUnionProps = PickAll<MyDUnion>
/* {
  type: "anon" | "google";
  name: string | undefined;
  idToken: string | undefined;
} */
// ✅
```

### focus on a specific `Key` (+IDE prompts and type checking)

> `ctrl`+`space` is OP

```
type DUnionName = PickAll<MyDUnion, 'name'>
/* { 
  name: string | undefined
} */
// ✅
```

### or a union of `Keys`

```
type DesiredProps = PickAll<
    MyDUnion | { fish: number },
    'type' | 'idToken' | 'fish'
>
/* {
    type: "anon" | "google" | undefined;
    idToken: string | undefined;
    fish: number | undefined;
} // ✅ */
```

### Gotchas

- Does not distinguish between `undefined` and `optional` properties. It can be done though and its on the todo.
- Extract literals directly.

#### DON'T do this:

`type` should be `"anon"` | `"google"`

```
type GoogleLike = PickAll<MyDUnion, 'type' | 'name'>

type g = GoogleLike['name' | 'type']
/* string | undefined  */
```

#### **Do** this:

```
type GoogleLikeTypes = GoogleLike['type']
/* "anon" | "google" */
// ✅

type GoogleLikeNames = GoogleLike['name']
/* string | undefined */
// ✅ (weird, be mindful)
```

---

#### EDIT

I forgot to mention the third parameter can be used to change the fallback type. The default is undefined, I think this is the most type-safe behavior, but you can also set it to whatever you want. For example, `PickAll<Union, Keys, never>` is equivalent to `Required<PickAll<Union, Keys>`>, or at least it would be if `Required` could infer the types like `PickAll`.

---

#### UPDATE 2

Stumbled into a "realistic" example of `KeyOf` and I think it would help shed some light on why it's a required part of the solution.

```
type Operations = {
  a: { responses: ApiResponse[] }
  b: { responses: ApiResponse[]; parameters: string[] }
}
```

Using built-in `keyof`, the "parameters" property is dropped, so this code will error:

```
type PickInner<T, P extends keyof T[keyof T]> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends { [K2 in P]: unknown } ? K : never]: T[K]
}

type q = PickInner<Operations, 'parameters'> 
// Type '"parameters"' does not satisfy the constraint '"responses"
```

but we can swap out that first `keyof` for `KeyOf<>` and suddenly our utility works:

```
- type PickInner<T, P extends keyof T[keyof T]> = {
+ type PickInner<T, P extends KeyOf<T[keyof T]>> = {
```

```
type q = PickInner<Operations, 'parameters'>
/* {
  b: {
      responses: ApiResponse[];
      parameters: string[];
  };
} */
```

Comment: What a well thought out and robust solution! Albeit, I do feel that the utility type definition is complicated to the point where it solves a different problem than what I envisioned in the question. Flattening the union type seems like a legitimate way to solve the task at hand, but I feel [@captain-yossarian from Ukraine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75108296/18620006) more directly solves the problem of selecting a single case from a discriminated union. I'm sure your answer will be extremely helpful for providing inspiration to solve a similar problem.

Comment: No problem. I really focused on how you wanted to access keys by name, which I wasn't able to do with yossarian's.

Comment: I see. Good perspective of approaching it

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the required key, you have to somehow tell the Typescript compiler

> Hey compiler, I want to know about this object, under a very specific case

In this case, you want to know about the object, when the `type ==='anon'`. So, taking your example,

```
type MyDUnion = { type: "anon"; name: string } | { type: "google"; idToken: string };

type SpclCase = MyDUnion & {type: "anon"}
```

By doing so, you're getting information about when theses two cases overlap. Now you can just index the `name` key directly.

```
type Name = SpclCase['name']
```

If you want to make this more robust, we can make sure that the narrowing type we use (`{type: 'anon'}` in this case), satisfies the required shape. Here's a little impromptu solution for that.

```
type DiscriminatorObj = { type: 'anon' }
type RequiredCase = DiscriminatorObj extends Pick<MyDUnion, "type"> ? DiscriminatorObj: never;
type SpclCase = (RequestBody & RequiredCase);
type Name = SpclCase['name']
```

I know its a little rough around the edges, but you can always extract this into generic functions and use them as you please. I merely showed you the fundamental logic. You can use it to make it more aesthetically pleasing.